# Leveraging Beautifulsoup within Scrapy

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have created a simple crawler with `Scrapy` that starts at a given link and follows all links within a given `DEPTH_LIMIT` that is adjusted each time I run the spider because of the project parameters. The script prints response URLs for the sake of simplicity.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from NONPROF.items import NonprofItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import re

class Nonprof(CrawlSpider):
    name = "my_scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com"]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['.*']),
             callback='parse_item',
             follow=True)
        ]

    def parse_item (self, response):
        print (response.url)
```

My current objective is to parse all visible text within a given depth from the starting url and use that data for topic modelling. I have done something similar in the past using `BeautifulSoup`, but I would like to leverage the following parsing language within my crawler.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    elif isinstance(element,bs.element.Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com').read()
print(text_from_html(html))
```

My difficulties in integrating the two is the logic behind a `BeautifulSoup` object and the `Response` from `Scrapy`.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: scrapy doc: [Selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) - and you don't need BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very least, you can just pass the HTML source contained in the `response.body` directly to `BeautifulSoup` to parse:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "lxml")
```

Note though, while this would work and you can use `soup` to HTML parse the desired data, you are not using a huge part of Scrapy - [`Scrapy` selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), the use of selectors in [Item Loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) etc. If I were you, I'd just make myself comfortable with the powers of Scrapy's way of extracting the data out of HTML.

Comment: when I pass response.body through the to create a BeautifulSoup object I get an error "NameError: name 'response' is not defined." I assumed that response was a sequence of urls that could be called through any commands to pull data from lists. I am new to Python and I am working from assumptions based in R logics which is obviously flawed.